# jQuery selector for any div id which contains a specified number, or higher

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem which i just cannot figure out how to solve! if you have any ideas, please assist :)

in my DOM there are a bunch of objets, as below:

```
<div id=Line1>1</div>
<div id=Line2>2</div>
<div id=Line3>3</div>
<div id=Line4>4</div>
<div id=Line5>5</div>
<div id=Line6>6</div>
<div id=Line7>7</div>
<div id=Line8>8</div>
<div id=Line9>9</div>
<div id=Line10>10</div>
```

I need to get a jQuery object containing any div which is Line6-10 (i.e. that contains 6 or above).... i've tried toying with .gt() but to no avail.

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select `<div>` with id which starts with 'Line', then reduce the matched set to those after the 5th (indexing is 0-based):

```
$('div[id^=Line]:gt(4)')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FpadN/)

Comment: this is relying on the sort order of the divs matching the index. If div with id `Line10` is the first div for example `gt()` will not work. Move the last 2 divs in your DEMO to the top and you see.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Yes that's true, and that's a reasonable approach for the problem given. It seems like a more probable use case that the OP would have some specific task for 'the last *n* lines' than he would for 'the lines containing 6, 7, 8, 9, 10'. The problem doesn't explicitly state which, but there's no reason to assume that they will not be in order. It actually seems more intuitive that 'lines' appear in numeric order, no? I definitely think this is a safer, more general answer than relying on the number being in the id.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible with a jQuery selector. The nicest way is the `slice` method:

```
$('div').slice(5); //select the sixth element and those after it
```

Alternatively, if you have to do the calculation (e.g. if not all the elements existed or they weren't in order) you could do something like this:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return (+this.id.slice(4) >= 6);
});
```

Comment: @freebird: slice() does not actualy take ids into consideration and assumes blindly the order of divs matches the ids. Move divs into a random order and slice() won't work.

Comment: @lonesomeday: The comment was aimed at freebird. I added the `@` now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var divs = $("div[id^='Line']").filter(function(){
    var text = "Line";
    var value = this.id.split(text)[1];

    return (value > 5);
});
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zpcj/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want specifically `Line6` to `Line10`, you can just use the `,` operator:

```
var q = $('#Line6,#Line7,#Line8,#Line9,#Line10');
```

You can create a selector dynamically, i.e. items from `x` to `y`:

```
var s = [];
for (var i = x; i <= y; i++) s.push('#Line' + i);
var q = $(s.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the quotes for ID attributes.

```
<div id=Line1>1</div>
      --^
```

Try using `filter` method.

```
$('div[id^="line"]').filter(function(){
   var = this.id.match(/\d+/g);
   return (id >= 6 && id <= 10)  
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jWY3Q/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**$("div[id^='Line5']").nextAll("div[id^='Line']")**

API about [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

API about [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution using [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$(function() {
   $elems = $("div[id^='Line']");
    $elems.filter(function() {
        var matches = this.id.match(/\d+/);
        var numb = parseInt(matches[0]);
        return ((numb > 5) && (numb <= 10));                
    });
});
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KzkDF/3/).